# How to show live chat dialog box on click of button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to show a live chat form in my website which will open on click of a button. The chat form that I need to show is in a separate file. How can I do that using jquery? It also needs to be responsive.

Something like this: https://www.websitealive.com/

Comment: Try providing some code with your question. A fiddle would be much appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this solution, This is just a layout. Just add a chat form inside the chatBox. Just Copy-Paste the complete code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Simple Chatbox</title>
<style type="text/css">
.chat-box {
    position:fixed;
    right:15px;
    bottom:0;
    box-shadow:0 0 0.1em #000;
}

.chat-closed {
    width: 250px;
    height: 35px;
    background: #8bc34a;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    border:1px solid #777;
    color: #000;
}

.chat-header {
    width: 250px;
    height: 35px;
    background: #8bc34a;
    line-height: 33px;
    text-indent: 20px;
    border:1px solid #777;
    border-bottom:none;
}

.chat-content{
    width:250px;
    height:300px;
    background:#ffffff;
    border:1px solid #777;
    overflow-y:auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.box{
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background:green;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    top: 11px;
    left: 10px;
    border:1px solid #ededed;
}

.hide {
    display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="chat-box">
<div class="chat-closed"> Chat Now </div>
<div class="chat-header hide"><div class="box"></div>Online Support</div>
<div class="chat-content hide">

*<br>
*<br>
*<br>
*<br>
*<br>
*<br>
*<br>
Your chat content...
*<br>
*<br>
*<br>
*<br>
*<br>
*<br>
*<br>
*<br>
*<br>
*<br>
*<br>
*<br>
*<br>
*<br>
Your chat content...
*<br>
*<br>
*<br>
*<br>
*<br>
*<br>
*<br>
</div>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".chat-closed").on("click",function(e){
        $(".chat-header,.chat-content").removeClass("hide");
        $(this).addClass("hide");
    });

    $(".chat-header").on("click",function(e){
        $(".chat-header,.chat-content").addClass("hide");
        $(".chat-closed").removeClass("hide");
    });
});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Very nice, but no scroll when chats "grow"

Comment: @LincesMarques : I have edited my code. You can refer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can load form into an iframe as below

"https://www.websitealive3.com/9/operator/guest/gDefault_v2.asp?cframe=chat&groupid=9&websiteid=77&departmentid=23&operatorid=21139&sessionid_=347739&iniframe=dock"

```
<iframe id="iframe_window" style="visibility:visible;width: 400px; height: 525px; border: 1px solid rgb(214, 214, 214); right: 20px; bottom: -1px; display: none" onload="this.style.visibility = 'visible';" src="Your file url"></iframe>
```

add an element which loads the `iframe`. I would assume an `a` tag as below

```
<a class="load_chat" href="#">Chat with us</a>
```

and write a js click event for above `a`

```
$('.load_chat').on('click',function(){
      $("#iframe_window").css('display','inline');
});
```